# Enable Text Field Block

Tags: jquery

See attached image. I disabled fields block by default, It will be only enabled if the checkbox is checked. eg If product1 checkbox is checked then product1 box fields will be enable.

Whats the best approach to do this, data-id on checkbox then check the fields? Stuck on this.

[image]

```
@foreach(get_products_by_parent_name("PC") as $product_id => $product_name)
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                          <h4><label class="p_name"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $product_id }}" name="scope[{{ $product_id }}][pid]"> {{ $product_name}} </label></h4>
                          <label>Quantity</label>
                          <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" 
                          name="scope[{{ $product_id }}][quantity]">
                          <label>Description</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="scope[{{ $product_id }}][description]" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               @endforeach
```

Comment: `data-id` sounds fine to me

Comment: but how to group fields under each data-id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
@foreach(get_products_by_parent_name("PC") as $product_id => $product_name)
             <div class="col-md-4 parent_{{$product_id}}">
                <div class="form-group">
                      <h4><label class="p_name"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $product_id }}" class="toggleTextBox" data-parent="parent_{{$product_id}}" name="scope[{{ $product_id }}][pid]"> {{ $product_name}} </label></h4>
                      <label>Quantity</label>
                      <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" 
                      name="scope[{{ $product_id }}][quantity]">
                      <label>Description</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="scope[{{ $product_id }}][description]" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
           @endforeach
```

JQuery:

```
$('.toggleTextBox').on('click',function(e){
  $('.' + $(this).attr('data-parent')).find('input,textarea').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

CSS:

```
.disabled { pointer-events:none; opacity: 0.5; }
```

Comment: How to toggle? remove and add class?

Comment: `$('.toggleTextBox').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).is(":checked"){
  $('.' + $(this).attr('data-parent')).find('input,textarea').removeClass('disabled'); }else {
 $('.' + $(this).attr('data-parent')).find('input,textarea').addClass('disabled'); }
});`

Answer (score 1):

It's a one-liner in jQuery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    $(this).parents("h4").siblings("input, textarea").prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

On a `checkbox` change event, you navigate the DOM up to the `h4` parent, then to its `input` or `textarea` siblings and to them you set the `disabled` prop as the opposite of the `checkbox` status.

Comment: Most times, all of `jQuery` is a one-liner in production, Stefano. But when you want people to easily read and understand your code so they learn proper techniques from your answer (like when you answer a question on [SO]), it is preferred you present it in a readable form, eventually briefly explaining what it does, eventually advising them minification services are available online.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thought the task was easy enough to remain understandable when collapsed, but you're probably right... I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: What I learned is that nothing is simple for someone missing the core concepts. The more one knows, the more they can understand from a glance.